# Problems with secondary monitor in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, monitor

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Asus EEE PC 1015bx.
I am a true novice with regards to Ubuntu.

I started running Ubuntu via usb stick but this seemed to stall often; I think that this has to do with the fact that all is run within RAM, of which this computer only holds 1 Gbyte.
When running via usb stick, I had a secondary monitor (Samsung SyncMaster 191T) connected and this seemed to work fine. The system automatically detected this and set the resolution and I was able to use both this and the laptop's monitors independently.

After installing Ubuntu on the hard drive alongside with Windows 7, I cannot get this to work anymore.

The system will let me mirror the monitors but when attempting to set the external monitor up as secondary, I am met with an error message that translates to something like "The chosen display configuration could not be used - the virtual size does not correspond to the available sizes: `Requested=(2304, 1024), minimum=(320, 200), maximum=(1280, 1280)`" followed by another error message that says something like "`GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._gnome_2drr_2derror_2dquark.Code3: requested virtuel size does not correspond to the available size: Requested=(2304, 1024), minimum=(320, 200), maximum=(1280, 1280)`".

I have read something somewhere regarding returning to the native driver. It would make sence that the usb setup would use this native driver but that the installation has updated to one containing errors.

I appreciate all the help I can get.

Answer (score 1):

I think that I have found the solution... or rather, the solution found me.

I read somewhere that the proprietary graphic drivers could cause the system to freeze.
Such a driver was active and I therefore deactivated this, as I had in fact experienced such freezes and wanted to avoid these.

When I rebooted the system, the GUI looked a bit different and I could not figure out how to make the launcher small as it was before. When downloading and running a tool for this, it stated that I was now running Unity 2D.

So my conclusion is that I had a proprietary driver installed which tried to provide 3D acceleration which my graphics card did not support.

Now, running with Unity 2D, I have a well working system and I am capable of using my secondary monitor together with my laptop as two separate monitors.

Also, my system has become much more stable.